# Hibernate "isInitialized" for lazy loaded fields

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Good day. I need to check initialization (loaded) of fields. For this task I try to use `Hibernate.isInitialized`. I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Contractor {
    /* ... */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contractor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Work> works = new ArrayList<Work>();

    /* ... */
}

@Entity
public class Work {
    /* ... */

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Contractor contractor;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Project project;

    /* ... */
}

@Entity
public class Project {
    /* ... */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Work> works = new ArrayList<Work>();

    /* ... */
}
```

Then I try to fetch entities by follow method:

```
List<Contractor> list = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Contractor c").getResultList();
    for (Contractor contractor : list) {
        Hibernate.initialize(contractor.getComments());
        Hibernate.initialize(contractor.getWorks());
        for (Work work : contractor.getWorks()) {
            Hibernate.initialize(work.getProject());
        }
    }
return list;
```

After that I check initialization sign of fields (for serialization) by two way:

```
Project p = contractor.getWorks().get(0).getProject();
Field f = Hibernate.getClass(p).getDeclaredField("works");
f.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println(Hibernate.isInitialized(f.get(p)));

System.out.println(Hibernate.isInitialized(contractor.getWorks().get(0).getProject().getWorks()));
```

And results are different for collections (true, false), but same for single objects. May be anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ensure your lazy relationships are fetched in the query itself and avoid having to check if they are initialized:

```
SELECT c FROM Contractor c JOIN FETCH c.comments JOIN FETCH c.works
```

The JOIN FETCH is a special type of join which simply ensures the loading of related entities. This would still just return the contractor objects but it will make sure its related comments and works have been loaded (even if they are declared as lazy).

**--Edit--**

Perhaps you can do the validations using the standard JPA API. Both the [PersistenceUnitUtils](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceUnitUtil.html) class and the [PersistenceUtil](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceUtil.html) have two helpful methods:

```
boolean isLoaded(java.lang.Object entity)
```

Which determines the load state of an entity belonging to the persistence unit.

```
boolean isLoaded(java.lang.Object entity, java.lang.String attributeName)
```

Which determines the load state of a given persistent attribute of an entity belonging to the persistence unit.

These too methods should do the trick for you, hopefully in a consistent way.

Comment: Yes, it is. And I use JOIN FECT, but not in all selects. But I try to write generalized serialization method (for not loaded lazy fields and already loaded by JOIN FECT lazy fields, so I need a method to dynamic check initialization.

Comment: @dmitrievanthony I have edited my answer with suggestions to use either `PersistenceUnitUtil` or `PersistenceUtil` classes. Although it looks like your question is more about why hibernate behavior is odd in this case you describe (which I don't know).

Comment: Yes, I try to use PersistenceUtil, but result is same.

Comment: These two mentioned classes are actually interfaces. To get an implementation of PersistenceUtil: Persistence.getPersistenceUtil()

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate persisting ArrayList - Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379955/hibernate-persisting-arraylist-issues)

I had a similar problem. Needed to annotate my class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tournament")
private List<String> registered;
```

changed to this

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable (name = "tournament_eligible", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
private List<String> username; // Contains a list of eligible members
```

This resolved that issue for me, though my lists just had String objects in them, I can't imagine it would be too much different.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use simple types like String. Am I understood , that this method doesn't applicable for Entities?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have't tried it with an entity yet. I would guess that it should work, as the annotation is referring to the collection not the entity. It shouldn't matter what is in the collection. But that's just me guessing.

Comment: not that "similar". You have a collection of non-entities, and the JPA spec and all docs I've seen for that (JPA2) say use ElementCollection. The OP has a collection of entity, and all docs for that require OneToMany (as is present). Consequently this is just a distraction

Comment: Thanks Neil. I'm going to have to worth with an entity database design next week so good to know so I don't start looking in the wrong place!!